# Как вывести несколько (не все) значений из массива в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Имеется примерный массив let tmp = [1, 2, 3, 4];
Как вывести из него 1ое и 3ое значение одной командой? Если пишу alert(tmp[0], tmp[2]); то выводится только первое значение массива - 1. Как сделать чтобы выводилось 1, 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У функции `alert` - один параметр.

```js
let tmp = [1, 2, 3, 4];
//alert([tmp[0], tmp[2]].join()); 
console.log([tmp[0], tmp[2]].join());
```